# Can I set a "File > Exit" keyboard shortcut in VS Code?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Often in my daily work I have many projects open in different instances of VS Code.

And I often find myself quitting using mouse and "File > Exit" to get all the windows back as soon as I reopen it tomorrow.

I can't find a way to add a keyboard shortcut for "File > Exit". It's possible?

Any other suggestion to avoid mouse-ing around?

Comment: Use keycombo: `Alt+F` `X`

Comment: Yes, it's not the same. Why I cannot set a shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for the command `workbench.action.quit` I think it is what you want.

```
{
    "key": "alt+q",                      //  or whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "workbench.action.quit"
}
```